# How to render text-mode emoji in a linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts, unicode

I would like to display specific unicode symbols in the Linux terminal rendered in monochrome like normal text, but many of the symbols I want are rendered as colour emoji (because I have noto-fonts-emoji installed, which I would prefer to keep). As an example, this smiley face symbol (\u263A): ☺.

Unicode has [variation sequences](http://unicode.org/faq/vs.html) that allow the formatting of specific characters to be specified, and in particular the [text-mode selector \uFE0E](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-variation-sequences.txt). However, the output of

```
printf '\u263A\uFE0E\n'
```

is still rendered as a full colour emoji. Why is the selector not working and how can I get the character to render in text mode?

Some more details:

- I'm currently using the terminal emulator `termite`. I am open to changing to a different terminal with better unicode support if would solve the problem.
- I have tried with both `bash` and `fish` but I'm not sure if the shell makes a difference.
- I'm on Arch linux but I would prefer a solution that works across distros.
- If I uninstall noto-fonts-emoji then the character renders as monochromatic text both with and without the text selector chracter, so I do have the necessary fonts for text style.